# To remove the mean value of the Fourier mode from the time series

Tags: time-series, fourier-transform

I am trying to implement a method for estimating the Power Spectrum Density function of a time-series following this paper: [PsyBoG: A scalable botnet detection method for large-scale
DNS traffic by Jonghoon Kwon et al. 2016.](http://ccs.korea.ac.kr/pds/COMNET16_KWON.pdf)

In their method they describe the PSD estimation as follows (emphasis mine):

> First, we specify a number of segments to use as input
>   time series for the PSD analysis. The number of segments
>   affects the frequency domain and its range. For a
>   high-quality PSD, the number of segments is selected from
>   among the powers of two, and we limit the length of the
>   number of segments to $2^{14} = 16,384$ to ensure a fast PSD
>   analysis. Note that the size of a single segment is 1 s,
>   and we apply the sliding time-window strategy to cover
>   a long input trace. Fig. 3 briefly shows the concept of the
>   segments, time window, and sliding window. **The second
>   step in the PSD estimation is to remove the mean value of
>   the Fourier mode from the time series.** This is a standard
>   technique [29] that allows a more accurate PSD estimation.
>   In the third step, we use a Hanning window that is used on
>   half-overlapped intervals to ensure the best signal-to-noise
>   ratio (SNR). The last step consists of operating the PSD
>   analysis for the specified segments of the input time series.

The citation ([29]) links through an article to the following book: [Discrete-Time Signal Processing - Second Edition](https://haseebsohail.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/discrete-time-signal-processing-by-alan-v-oppenheim.pdf). This does mention removing the mean from the time-series (i.e. centering the data) and it does mention averaging the fourier coefficients obtained by each of the sliding windows, but I don't think that that is what they meant with the bold sentence.

So my questions are as follows:

- What is meant with **the mean value of the Fourier Mode**?
- How would one 'remove' this value from a time-series?

---

Edit.

I found another bit of information on the method in [29]:

> Given the interval, the first step in PSD estimation is to remove the mean value of the Fourier mode from the
>   time series. This is a standard technique (see [12]) that allows more accurate PSD estimation. This mean-removal
>   subtracts the estimated static error from the signal over the interval.

([12] is the book mentioned before).

From this I conclude that the goal is to remove static noise, which would appear in the Fourier transformation as a constant value equal to the Variance of the noise. So that answers the first question. I guess that this gives us an estimate of the noise in our time-series. But how would you remove that from the time-series?

Comment: In fourier series, the first term, i.e. $a_0$ is often called the _average value_ of the signal. because other terms are associated with sine waves whose average values are zero. This average value can cause serious problems in filtering applications. So it is sometimes removed. The trick is simple: lower the amplitude of the signal by a constant term which is equal to the mean value, $a_0$

Comment: @polfosol So is that centering the other coefficients ($a_1 ... a_n$) or removing the mean of the data? Because if it is the latter, why do they describe it as the 'mean of the Fourier modes', instead of the mean of the data?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't notice at the first glance. Now that I read it more thoroughly, I think the mean value of the fourier mode has nothing to do with the mean value of the signal. Look at [the second paragraph in here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation#Periodogram).

Comment: I found another description (in the paper directly cited in [29]) which I edited in the question.

Comment: @polfosol it seems they remove a mean value from the spectrum, not from the time signal. So I think what they do is $Y(k) = e^{i \text{arg}(X(k))} |\, \max(0,|X(k)|-\mu)$ where $\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} |X(k)|$ and $X(k)$ is the discrete Fourier transform of the time series $x(n)$. Doing this, they hope removing some white noise (whose spectrum is aproximatively constant in amplitude)